# How to define url routes with wildcard in Play2?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, url-routing

I am using **Play 2** with Scala. I want to define a router rule so that any wrong url gets redirect to the root:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index(ignore="")

# global fall over
GET     /*ignore                    controllers.Application.index(ignore)
```

This is ugly, I have to define a useless parameter to satisfy the syntax...any idea how to remove that `ignore` parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create object extending `GlobalSettings` in your `app` directory:

```
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Global extends GlobalSettings{
  override def onHandlerNotFound(request: RequestHeader) = {
    Future.successful(Redirect("/"))
  }
}

//routes
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
```

Docs: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal

Comment: Treat it as error handling...why I did not think like this. Thanks!